# WinForms MDI : How to show MdiChild in Parent TableLayoutPanel's line?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I'm following [this tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNr_iNoXahQ) for create a multipage app in Winform. My MdiParent have

MainForm IsMdiParent = true

```
HomeForm frmHomeForm;
private void HomeIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(frmHomeForm == null)
        {
            frmHomeForm = new HomeForm();
            frmHomeForm.MdiParent = this;
            frmHomeForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            frmHomeForm.Activate();
        }
    }
```

If someone can help, it's first time I used MDI.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Did your `Click` event handler get called at all? It's not possible to provide a good answer to your question, without your question including a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. So, you can either improve the question, or do a little debugging yourself.

Comment: You could declare your form like this : `HomeForm frmHomeForm = null;`

Comment: yes when I debug the click event is fired and I pass on frmHomeForm.show()

Comment: is there a control on the MDI Parent form that is covering the whole Parent form ? If that is the case than all MDI Child windows will never be visible but will always be underneath that control

Comment: @GuidoG frmHomeForm is already null when I debug. I make it explecitly but there is no change..

Comment: Does it not get to the line "MdiParent = this" then? if you are saying it never changes

Comment: yes @GuidoG I have a TableLayoutPanel.. I want my child appear in the second line of it How can I do that ?

Comment: you cannot, that is how MDI works. All MDI Child windows can only appear on the Parent Form, and only on the area on the Parent form that is not covered by any other control

Comment: ok thank @GuidoG I will try it with empty MdiParent.

Comment: It's work fine thanks a lot @GuidoG

Comment: no problem, glad i could help

Comment: Don't include the solution as part of the question. If you find a good solution, post it as answer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei you'r right.. that is why it's call answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to show MdiChild on my MdiParent who was covered by another control. I remove the control on my MdiParent and my MdiChild now appear correctly in empty area.